# Python handling system output without returns

Tags: python, input, printing, output, system

I have two programs. The functions inside the first program return some message and contains many `print`s. So, I import the first program functions into the second program and use the return values. However, I need the `print`s of the first program too. How can I get them?

FYI I cannot append `print` values in the return. Is there any way to get all the prints used by the program?

Example code:

First program1.py

```
class Test():
    def first(self,name):
        print "first print"
        print "second print"
        print "third print"
        #do some thing..
        return {"sucess":"end result"}
```

Second program2.py

```
from firstprog import Test
result = Test().first("testing")
return result + "first program prins here"
```

Comment: Please provide an example code of what you are explaining so we can easily help you. We do not require the full code or the real code but a code snippet that exemplifies what are you currently executing.

Comment: Calls to functions containing `print()` in the first python file should be displayed. Post an example of the code that you are using for each file.

Comment: I realized I assumed in my answer you were importing the function from the other python file. Is it the case?

Comment: ill add code @CristianRamon-Cortes

Comment: yes see above example sample code@FunkySayu

Comment: @prabakar.py remember to format the code when needed. Btw, when you talk about print I think you are really talking about `redirecting the stdout/stderr` from those functions to the new program. Won't post a reply tho because @FunkySayu provided already a nice answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can patch the `sys.stdout` by making it your own `StringIO` object.

```
import StringIO
import sys

def my_function():
    print("foo")
    return 5

stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = my_stdout = StringIO.StringIO()

result = my_function()

sys.stdout = stdout
print(my_stdout.getvalue())  # prints foo
print(result)  # prints 5
```